# Magic Mouse on Bootcamp

Tags: windows, macos, mac, mouse, boot-camp

I recently got my new iMac and have installed Windows 7 on it in Bootcamp.

I have a Magic Mouse which was working perfectly in Mac OS. Then I installed Windows 7 along with the drivers for Windows which can be downloaded through Bootcamp. I was not able to get my Magic Mouse to work. Then I read, that it might help booting into Mac OS, remove the Magic Mouse, then boot back into Windows and add the Magic Mouse from Bluetooth Devices. That worked.

Now I have booted back into Mac OS and added the mouse again and it's working. Then, if I boot into Windows again it's not working. It is as if the mouse will only work on one side at a time.

Does anyone have an idea how to get my Magic Mouse to work in both Mac OS and Windows 7?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the drivers then it worked.

Remember to give Windows a few seconds to pair with the Magic Mouse. If it does not pair, try clicking a button on the Magic Mouse to wake it up from standby.